# Make every <td> width fit its content instead of the <td> with the longest content in the same column

Tags: html, css, width

I have a table with only one cell within each row. The words appended into each cell varies. Some are short while some are longer, however the width of every cell is the same as the width of the cell with the longest content.

Is it possible in css/html to make each cell width fit its own content instead of the cell with the longest content?

```
$("#chatdisplay").append("<tr bgcolor='#ccffcc'><td><b>" + arr[i].date_time_sent + "</b><br/>" + arr[i].sender + ":" + "<br>" + arr[i].message + "<br></td></tr>");

$("#chatdisplay").append("&nbsp;");
```

CSS

```
table,th,td,tr {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
table {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

[image]

Comment: No, `table` has not that flexibility. 
Try `div`

Comment: Each message should be its own table...then it would work,

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain, you can, but it's really not the way. Check my answer with the example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do this - **you can**, using `display: inline-block` on the `td` elements, however this really **isn't recommended** and it's not the way to do this.

You can use the table for the structure (even though you don't really need this) and you can just use div blocks for that.

Here is an example for all 3 options:

```css
table,th,td,tr {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
table {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#tbl1 td {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #ccffcc;
  display: inline-block;
}
#tbl2 div.container {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #ccffcc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
}
#tbl2 tr, #tbl2 td {
  padding: 0;
}
div.blocks div.container {
  padding: 4px 20px;
}
div.blocks div.container div.content {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #ccffcc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
}
```

```html
td with display: inline-block:<br />
<table id="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <td>This is some content</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>This is a cell with much more content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
div's insinde td<br />
<table id="tbl2">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="container">This is some content</div>
    </td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>
      <div class="container">text</div>
    </td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>
      <div class="container">This is a cell with much more content</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br />
Div's only:<br />
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">This is some content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">This is a cell with much more contentThis is a cell with much more contentThis is a cell with much more contentThis is a cell with much more contentThis is a cell with much more contentThis is a cell with much more contentThis is a cell with much more contentThis is a cell with much more contentThis is a cell with much more content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Dekel, thanks for your suggestions! With your suggestions, I went on to append <div><tr><td> *array items* </td></tr></div> for each loop. Now the length of each "highlighted bubble" is only as long as its content within! Yours is a helpful post with awesome examples!

Comment: You are welcome, however I really don't understand why you wrap the `tr` element with `div`. This is not a correct structure...

Comment: I played around appending divs inside table cells and vice versa, appearance wise, the first seems to give me the appearance I'm looking for in the chat message display.